# How to make a proper name input program in python

Tags: python

I am at the part where I ask the user for their name. So far I got this:

```
# Import stuff
import time

# Create empty variable
Name = ""

# Ask their name
while Name = ""
    Name = input("What is your name? ")
    print("")
print(Name)
print("")
time.sleep(3)
```

So if the user inputs nothing, it repeats the question. But when the user inputs an integer or a float it registers this as a valid name.

How will I be able to make it so that if the `Name` variable is an integer or a float, it will respond with `"Please enter a valid name"` and repeat the question?

Comment: You could try using the float, and int methods to convert the string to those types. But wrap that in a try except, then if it succeeds, get the user to reenter the input, otherwise you know its not a number

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: By default the type of `input` is `string`. You can convert using `int` and use conditions to check if it is an integer

Comment: This is python 3. Sorry I didn't mention that earlier

Comment: Your code seems to be malformed. I have answered to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I'm updating my answer to simplify the code and make it more readable.**

The below function is a function that I would use in my own code, I would consider it to be more "proper" than my old answer.

```
from string import ascii_letters

def get_name():
    name = input("What is your name?\n: ").strip().title()

    while not all(letter in ascii_letters + " -" for letter in name):
        name = input("Please enter a valid name.\n: ").strip().title()

    return name
```

To break this down, the line `all(letter in ascii_letters + " -" for letter in name)` means "if each letter in name is not an alphabetical character, a space, or a hyphen".

The part `letter in ascii_letters + " -"` checks to see if a letter is in the string `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ -"`.

This is repeated by the next part, `for letter in name`, for every character in the string. This will effectively return a list of booleans, `[True, True, True, ...]` where any `False` is a character that did not pass the conditional. Next, this list is passed to the `all()` function, which returns  `True` if all of the list items are `True`.

After the `all()` is executed, conditional is reversed, allowing the loop to continue on the existence of a single failed character.

---

**Old answer is as follows, it will still be useful.**

This function should work well for you. Simply check if the string the user entered is alpha characters only, otherwise ask again.

Notice the use of `str.isalpha()`.

```
def get_name():
    name = input("What is your name?\n: ").strip().title()

    while not (name.replace("-", "") and
               name.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").isalpha()):
        name = input("Please enter a valid name.\n: ").strip().title()

    return name
```

Checking `if name` will check if the string is empty, and using `str.strip()` on the values returned will remove any surrounding whitespace (stray spaces) to the left or right of the user input.

The `str.replace("-", "")` eliminates hyphens while checking validity. Thanks for pointing this out **@AGN Gazer**.

Now you can just call the function later in your script, or store it for later.

```
name = get_name().title()

print("You said your name was " + name + ".)
```

The `str.title()` converts the letter of each word in a string to uppercase. For example, if I entered my name "jacob birkett", the output (and subsequent value of `name` would be "Jacob Birkett".

Take a look at the documentation for [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha), [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) and [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title).

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, although I have come across a problem when testing your code. It only seems to work the second time I input something. The first time it asks the question nothing seems to work.

Comment: @Caeruleas Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out. See my edited answer.

Comment: Well, although this is the accepted answer, I don't think it's the correct way to check. Names like Mary-Ann would not be accepted, same for names like Kim Robert.

Comment: @spikespaz Thanks a lot! This solved my question. I appreciate the extra info to help better explain your answer as well :)

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle Reload your page and see my edit. This is fixed.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. But you would also have to add spaces. And then, the code looks a little messy.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle What do you mean "add spaces"? The strings are not mutable; the result will pass the check because the replacement is performed only within the conditional evaluation. The output would include the hyphens.

Comment: @spikespaz sorry to bother you again but typing "Jacob Grey" is not a valid name because it has the space in the middle? "Jacob-Grey" works though.

Comment: @Caeruleas Fixed. That was a stupid oversight of me.

Comment: @Caeruleas I've updated the answer with a much less convoluted function at the top. Either will work, but I don't know which one is more performant. Probably the bottom one, because the `str.isalpha()` is executed in C, but the top one is much nicer to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like `.isalpha()` as this will return True if all the string contains all the alphabets:

```
while True:
    Name = input("Please enter a valid name.\n: ")
    if name.isalpha()
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid name.")
        continue

    print(Name)
```

Or You can try exception handling in python as (but this should be prevented):

```
try :
    int(Name)
    print("Please enter a valid name")
    ...

except:
    print("Accepted")
    ...
```

This will check if the input is an integer print the error.

Comment: You shouldn't be using try/except for these things. This is simple enough to do without catching a thrown error, and suppressing errors should not be your first line-of-attack when validating user input.

Comment: Thank You, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
while Name == "" or Name.isnumeric() == True:
    Name = input("What is your name? ")
    print("")
```

Here if the Name is any numeric value it will ask again, But if the name is like alphanumeric it will accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
This will check if variable `Name` containing numeric data or not.

```
import time
Name = ""
while Name == "" :
    Name = input("What is your name? ")
    if not Name.isalpha():
        print "It is containing numberic characher or characters"
        Name = ""
    print("")

print(Name)
print("")
time.sleep(3)
```

You also can try if name is like "harsha-biyani":

```
import time
Name = ""
while Name == "" :
    Name = input("What is your name? ")
    if any(i.isdigit() for i in Name):
        print "It is containing numberic characher or characters"
        Name = ""
    print("")

print(Name)
print("")
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Checking `str.isdigit()` for every character in the string is redundant, `str.isalpah()` does the same thing.

Comment: @spikespaz You are correct

Comment: @spikespaz What would `isalpha()` return for `'Maria-Elena'`???

Comment: No @spikespaz is wrong

Comment: @Harsha If you restore back checking of every character, I'll delete my answer

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
Name.isalpha()
```

`"3".isalpha()`

> False

```
"anna".isalpha()
```

> True